# How to Hide textView From listView item from list view in android

Tags: android, listview

I Have a list view. in which i have a textview for status. now i want to disable that text view when when status is cancelled. in this list item i have a textview(Ride Status) now when ride status got cancelled when i m setting the adapter i want ti hide the cancel ride text view from list item. i have tried but this is not working for me. thanks in adveance.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final DrawerListItemHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new DrawerListItemHolder();

        holder.mRideStatus = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ride_status);
            holder.mCancelRide = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cancle_ride);
            holder.mViewRide = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.view_ride);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (DrawerListItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        String rideType = BravoDataController.getInstance(mContext)
                .getTripStatusDescription(
                        mMyRides.get(position).getTripStatusCode());
        holder.mRideStatus.setText(rideType);

        holder.mRideStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(BravoDataController
                .getInstance(mContext).getTripStatusColor(
                        mMyRides.get(position).getTripStatusCode())));

        if (rideType.equals(ConstantsUtils.CANCELLED)) {
            holder.mCancelRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: have your condition working perfectly.?

Comment: Any error you are getting by running this code? Please debug and check whether you "if" condition is getting executed or not.

Comment: @dhuma1981 :- it is working perfectly for first three list view item. but after three item is hide cancel ride text view  either ride status is cancelled or any other

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition in getView to

```
if (rideType.equals(ConstantsUtils.CANCELLED)) {
            holder.mCancelRide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
        holder.mCancelRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and call this `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when the flag is changed.

Comment: There is no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() I guess.

Comment: there will be something where status is getting cancelled, by just calling notifyDataSetChanged will update the listview